# iOS Cell Reusing Changing Colors

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is a common problem, I researched but I could not find the problem.

My code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
     let cell1=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(textCellIdentifier) as! MessageCell
     cell1.setCell(swiftBlogs[row])
     return cell1

}
```

MessageCell.swift

```
func setCell(message:Message) {
    messageLabel.text = message.text
    if message.incoming != (tag == incomingTag) {
        var layoutAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute
        var layoutConstant: CGFloat

        if message.incoming {
            tag = incomingTag
            bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.incoming
            bubbleImageView.highlightedImage = bubbleImage.incomingHighlighed
            messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            layoutAttribute = .Left
            layoutConstant = 10
        } else { // outgoing
            tag = outgoingTag

            if message.isSent == 1 {
                bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.outgoing
            }
            if message.isSent == 0 {
                bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.notYetSent
            }
            bubbleImageView.highlightedImage = bubbleImage.outgoingHighlighed
            messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            layoutAttribute = .Right
            layoutConstant = -10
        }



        let constraints: NSArray = contentView.constraints
        let indexOfConstraint = constraints.indexOfObjectPassingTest { (constraint, idx, stop) in
            return (constraint.firstItem as! UIView).tag == bubbleTag && (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Left || constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Right)
        }
        contentView.removeConstraint(constraints[indexOfConstraint] as! NSLayoutConstraint)
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: layoutAttribute, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: layoutConstant))
    }

}
```

Let me explain my code: As you can see in `setCell` If `message.incoming` is true then cell should be on the left side. If false then cell should be on the right side. **This is working without any problem.** But as you can see, I have one more if statement. If `message.isSent` == 1 then I am changing `image` property of `bubbleImageView` and my problem starts here. `bubbleImage.outgoing` is blue image and `bubbleImage.notYetSent` is red image. When I start scrolling cell colors are changing even `isSent` value is not changing.

I have no problem with first if statement (`message.incoming` check.) everythings looks great but colors are changing. How can I resolve this problem?

Example:

**Before Scroll:**

[image]

**After Scroll:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on how you're using `tag`, but this line:

```
if message.incoming != (tag == incomingTag) {
```

will prevent you from reaching this code:

```
        if message.isSent == 1 {
            bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.outgoing
        }
        if message.isSent == 0 {
            bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.notYetSent
        }
```

in the case of cell reuse.  This code needs to run every time you set up a cell and that cell is an outgoing message.  Consider moving that part of the setup outside of the first conditional:

```
if message.incoming != (tag == incomingTag) {
    // setup code

}

if !message.incoming {
    if message.isSent == 1 {
        bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.outgoing
    }
    if message.isSent == 0 {
        bubbleImageView.image = bubbleImage.notYetSent
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.. I removed if message.incoming != (tag == incomingTag) { then it worked well. My hours... :) Thank you

Comment: It kind of looks like `tag` was meant to check how the current cell is configured, and if it is already configured like you want it then you don't have to reconfigure the cell.  But if that is the case, then `tag` should be a property of the cell and saved with the cell.  That is what was confusing me.